# telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused when trying to connect running docker image

Tags: docker, ubuntu-18.04

I am having ubuntu 18.04 running on a server. I am got a JasperServer image running on docker in it. I am trying to access it from my system. But it throws the following error:

```
jamshaid@jamshaid:~$ telnet my_server_address 9095
Trying my_server_ip...

telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
```

Here is the output for `sudo docker ps -a`

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                   COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                           NAMES
69c31ba800ab        bitnami/jasperreports   "/app-entrypoint.sh …"   5 hours ago         Up 5 hours          0.0.0.0:9095->8080/tcp, 0.0.0.0:443->8443/tcp   ceyedev_jasperreports_1
2a7cb72da0c7        bitnami/mariadb:10.3    "/opt/bitnami/script…"   5 hours ago         Up 5 hours          0.0.0.0:3306->3306/tcp                          ceyedev_mariadb_1
```

if I telnet on localhost, it connects and then connection closes which means it is running well.
Here is the output when I telnet it from localhost:

```
ceyedev@ub18servertiny:~$ telnet localhost 9095
Trying ::1...
Connected to localhost.localdomain.
Escape character is '^]'.
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

Here is the docker-compose file

```
version: '2'
services:
  mariadb:
    restart: always
    image: 'bitnami/mariadb:10.3'
    environment:
      - MARIADB_USER=bn_jasperreports
      - MARIADB_DATABASE=bitnami_jasperreports
      - ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes
    ports:
      - 3306:3306      
    volumes:
      - 'mariadb_data:/bitnami'
  jasperreports:
    restart: always
    image: 'bitnami/jasperreports'
    environment:
      - MARIADB_HOST=mariadb
      - MARIADB_PORT_NUMBER=3306
      - JASPERREPORTS_DATABASE_USER=bn_jasperreports
      - JASPERREPORTS_DATABASE_NAME=bitnami_jasperreports
      - ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes
    ports:
      - '9095:8080'
      - '443:8443'
    volumes:
      - 'jasperreports_data:/bitnami'
    depends_on:
      - mariadb
volumes:
  mariadb_data:
    driver: local
  jasperreports_data:
    driver: local
```

Here is the output for `sudo docker logs container_id_for_jasper`
[image]

I can telnet other ports from my local machine but having an issue with this one. Any ideas? thanks

keeping in the view of bullet 2 from answers, I executed the below command and found that 9095 is allocated by the server. Any ideas, please?

```
ceyedev@ub18servertiny:~$ netstat -atn
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State      
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5432          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0    244 10.0.114.15:22          182.185.223.147:54326   ESTABLISHED
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 ::1:5432                :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::9095                 :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::3306                 :::*                    LISTEN
```

Comment: I don't understand, which telnet command is not working. Can you add the telnet command to your first shell snippet (Trying my_server_ip...)?

Comment: @ElmarBrauch just updated the snippet. Please have a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your question, you know:

- Docker container is running
- Docker container is listening to port 9095
- telnet from Linux server to docker container is working
- telnet from other client somewhere in Internet to docker container is NOT working

I guess your Ubuntu server is not accepting incoming requests from Internet on port 9095.
There can be many reasons for that:

- Your server has firewall settings, which block connection
- Your server did not publish port 9095 to Internet
- Your client has no Internet access, when using port 9095

So I would investigate these aspects.
The docker part seems to be ok, because telnet to localhost is working.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. regarding your first point, if the server has firewall settings, it should not allow every incoming request from my local pc. I can access other ports from my local pc. Can it just block the traffic to 9095? 
For the third point, the internet is working pretty fine.

Comment: I just updated the question. would you please have a look

Comment: Are you able to describe your server a little bit more?
Is it a server in a cloud (AWS, Azure, etc)?
How is the server connected to the Internet (loadbalancer, DMZ, directly, reverse proxy)?
Which other services are running on your server? It has port 443 open - is there an Apache Webserver or something like this? Can you telnet against port 443?

Answer (score 1):

To people who got there and didn't find solution:

Make sure your web server is listening on 0.0.0.0 to listen ALL interfaces, including docker bridge to outer network

Answer (score 0):

I take no credits for this, but this helped me:

> The problem is that services expecting to connect to “localhost” break when you containerize them if you have the service running outside the container. You have to pass the service the IP address of the host machine in order for the containerized service to connect to it. localhost inside the container doesn’t leave the container.

See:
https://forums.docker.com/t/connection-refused-when-you-try-to-connect-to-a-service-port-started-on-host/11508/9