# Able to access Spring Boot service locally but not over the Internet

Tags: spring-boot, centos7, firewall

I have a server running on my local network that is listening on port 8080. This server is providing a RESTful interface
that is supposed to return some JSON to a client. This server is running on a machine running CentOS 7. I have Port 8080 open in Firewalld,
and my SELinux is set to Permissive mode.

I have a firewall that has been configured to receive HTTP requests and forward them to my server on Port 8080. I also have a URL: [www.myservice.net](http://www.myservice.net), which is configured to go to the IP address that my firewall is connected to.

My server's local address is 10.20.2.101. When I access the server using:

```
http://10.20.2.101:8080/getinfo
```

I have no problems. My server returns the JSON that I am expecting.

Unfortunately, when I attempt to access the server from outside my network,using:

```
http://www.myservice.net:8080/getinfo
```

I get connection failures. The connection attempt consistently times out.

I have used tcpdump to see what was going on (I suspected my firewall mighthave been misconfigured), and what I am seeing is that the
HTTP request is reaching the port on my server in both cases, and the server sees the HTTP request and processes it when I make the request locally. Unfortunately, when I make the request from outside my network, the request reaches the server but in the form of a lot of zero- sized packets and the HTTP request is not responded to at all!

Can someone provide some idea of why HTTP requests are not getting through on an open port? Why is my server unable to process requests from outside my local network? Is there some other thing I need to configure on my Linux machine that will allow the server to process outside requests?

TCPDUMP Logs (assuggested by Elmar Brauch):

1. This is what I get when I do a tcpdump and then go to http://10.20.2.101:8080/getinfo :

   ```
    [root@Server1 ~] sudo tcpdump --interface any -vvv port 8080
    cpdump: listening on any, link-type LINUX_SLL (Linux cooked), capture size 262144 bytes

    11:22:18.259543 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
        Server1.webcache > 10.20.2.102.49234: Flags [S.], cksum 0x2d9e (correct), seq 2007505089, ack 3327267992, win 29200, options [mss 1460,nop,nop,sackOK,nop,wscale 7], length 0
    11:22:18.259555 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 128, id 34480, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 40)
        10.20.2.102.49233 > Server1.webcache: Flags [.], cksum 0xf3b7 (correct), seq 1, ack 1, win 8212, length 0
    11:22:18.259741 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 128, id 34481, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 40)
    10.20.2.102.49234 > Server1.webcache: Flags [.], cksum 0xc06c (correct), seq 1, ack 1, win 8212, length 0
    11:22:18.262208 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 128, id 34482, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 515)
        10.20.2.102.49233 > Server1.webcache: Flags [P.], cksum 0x344c (correct), seq 1:476, ack 1, win 8212, length 475: HTTP, length: 475
            GET /home/devices HTTP/1.1
            Host: 10.20.2.101:8080
            Connection: keep-alive
            Cache-Control: max-age=0
            Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
            User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.102 Safari/537.36
            Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
            Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
            Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9

    11:22:18.262283 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 25534, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 40)
        Server1.webcache > 10.20.2.102.49233: Flags [.], cksum 0x1104 (correct), seq 1, ack 476, win 237, length 0
    11:22:19.058618 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 25535, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 1500)
        Server1.webcache > 10.20.2.102.49233: Flags [.], cksum 0x72ed (correct), seq 1:1461, ack 476, win 237, length 1460: HTTP, length: 1460
            HTTP/1.1 200 
            Content-Type: application/json
            Content-Length: 4157
            Date: Fri, 23 Oct 2020 15:22:19 GMT
            Keep-Alive: timeout=60
            Connection: keep-alive

    {"devices":[{"name":"Generic Z-Wave Switch","label":"Upstairs Bathroom ","type":"Generic Z-Wave Switch","id":"48","date":"2020-10-23T12:44:43+0000","model":null,"manufacturer":null,"capabilities":["Switch","Polling","Configuration","Refresh","Actuator"],"attributes":{"switch":"on","dataType":"ENUM","values":["on","off"]},"commands":[{"command":"configure"},{"command":"flash"},{"command":"off"},{"command":"on"},{"command":"poll"},{"command":"refresh"}]},{"name":"Generic Z-Wave Switch","label":"Master Bedroom","type":"Generic Z-Wave Switch","id":"33","date":"2020-10-22T05:24:20+0000","model":null,"manufacturer":null,"capabilities":["Switch","Polling","Configuration","Refresh","Actuator"],"attributes":{"switch":"off","dataType":"ENUM","values":["on","off"]},"commands":[{"command":"configure"},{"command":"flash"},{"command":"off"},{"command":"on"},{"command":"poll"},{"command":"refresh"}]},{"name":"Generic Z-Wave Dimmer","label":"Soft Light Left","type":"Generic Z-Wave Dimmer","id":"35","date":"2020-10-23T07:59:29+0000","model":null,"manufacturer":null,"capabilities":["Switch","Polling","Configuration","SwitchLevel","Refresh","Actuator","ChangeLevel"],"attributes":{"level":"50","dataType":"ENUM","values":["on","off"],"switch":"off"},"commands":[{"command":"configure"},{"command":"flash"}[!http]
    11:22:19.058654 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 25536, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 1500)
        Server1.webcache > 10.20.2.102.49233: Flags [.], cksum 0x2556 (correct), seq 1461:2921, ack 476, win 237, length 1460: HTTP
    11:22:19.058813 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 25537, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 1433)
        Server1.webcache > 10.20.2.102.49233: Flags [P.], cksum 0x720c (correct), seq 2921:4314, ack 476, win 237, length 1393: HTTP
    11:22:19.058847 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 128, id 34495, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 40)
        10.20.2.102.49233 > Server1.webcache: Flags [.], cksum 0xe674 (correct), seq 476, ack 2921, win 8212, length 0
    11:22:19.099351 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 128, id 34496, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 40)
        10.20.2.102.49233 > Server1.webcache: Flags [.], cksum 0xe108 (correct), seq 476, ack 4314, win 8207, length 0
    11:22:19.836579 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 128, id 19059, offset 0, flags [none], proto TCP (6), length 40)
   ```
2. This is what I get when I do a tcpdump and then go to http://www.myservice.net:8080/getinfo :

   ```
    [root@Server1 ~] sudo tcpdump --interface any -vvv port 8080
    cpdump: listening on any, link-type LINUX_SLL (Linux cooked), capture size 262144 bytes

    11:30:03.179202 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 128, id 62073, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
        10.20.2.102.50314 > Server1.webcache: Flags [S], cksum 0x1bef (correct), seq 1931050208, win 64240, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 8,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0
    11:30:03.179300 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
        Server1.webcache > 10.20.2.102.50314: Flags [S.], cksum 0xdf0a (correct), seq 2621843822, ack 1931050209, win 29200, options [mss 1460,nop,nop,sackOK,nop,wscale 7], length 0
    11:30:03.179525 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 128, id 62074, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
        10.20.2.102.50315 > Server1.webcache: Flags [S], cksum 0x7b62 (correct), seq 1808868532, win 64240, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 8,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0
    11:30:03.179586 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
        Server1.webcache > 10.20.2.102.50315: Flags [S.], cksum 0x7832 (correct), seq 3006388430, ack 1808868533, win 29200, options [mss 1460,nop,nop,sackOK,nop,wscale 7], length 0
    11:30:03.429672 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 128, id 62075, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
        10.20.2.102.50317 > Server1.webcache: Flags [S], cksum 0x595c (correct), seq 1229678910, win 64240, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 8,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0
    11:30:03.429760 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
        Server1.webcache > 10.20.2.102.50317: Flags [S.], cksum 0x57e7 (correct), seq 446918562, ack 1229678911, win 29200, options [mss 1460,nop,nop,sackOK,nop,wscale 7], length 0
    11:30:04.178228 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 128, id 62076, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
        10.20.2.102.50314 > Server1.webcache: Flags [S], cksum 0x1bef (correct), seq 1931050208, win 64240, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 8,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0
    11:30:04.178281 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    Server1.webcache > 10.20.2.102.50314: Flags [S.], cksum 0xdf0a (correct), seq 2621843822, ack 1931050209, win 29200, options [mss 1460,nop,nop,sackOK,nop,wscale 7], length 0
    11:30:04.180307 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 128, id 62077, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
        10.20.2.102.50315 > Server1.webcache: Flags [S], cksum 0x7b62 (correct), seq 1808868532, win 64240, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 8,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0
    11:30:04.180352 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
        Server1.webcache > 10.20.2.102.50315: Flags [S.], cksum 0x7832 (correct), seq 3006388430, ack 1808868533, win 29200, options [mss 1460,nop,nop,sackOK,nop,wscale 7], length 0
    11:30:04.430286 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 128, id 62078, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
        10.20.2.102.50317 > Server1.webcache: Flags [S], cksum 0x595c (correct), seq 1229678910, win 64240, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 8,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0
    11:30:04.430369 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
        Server1.webcache > 10.20.2.102.50317: Flags [S.], cksum 0x57e7 (correct), seq 446918562, ack 1229678911, win 29200, options [mss 1460,nop,nop,sackOK,nop,wscale 7], length 0
    11:30:04.999555 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 128, id 18649, offset 0, flags [none], proto TCP (6), length 40)
        gateway.49152 > Server1.webcache: Flags [S], cksum 0x3912 (correct), seq 5001, win 0, length 0
    11:30:04.999680 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 44)
        Server1.webcache > gateway.49152: Flags [S.], cksum 0x9a7a (correct), seq 1713090206, ack 5002, win 29200, options [mss 1460], length 0
    11:30:04.999877 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 57772, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 75)
        gateway.49152 > Server1.webcache: Flags [R.], cksum 0x492b (correct), seq 1:36, ack 1, win 65468, length 35 [RST+ (Ref.Id: ?suf6sk4amEkP4kj2W8w4]
    11:30:05.202582 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    Server1.webcache > 10.20.2.102.50315: Flags [S.], cksum 0x7832 (correct), seq 3006388430, ack 1808868533, win 29200, options [mss 1460,nop,nop,sackOK,nop,wscale 7], length 0
    11:30:05.602523 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
        Server1.webcache > 10.20.2.102.50314: Flags [S.], cksum 0xdf0a (correct), seq 2621843822, ack 1931050209, win 29200, options [mss 1460,nop,nop,sackOK,nop,wscale 7], length 0
    11:30:05.802578 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
        Server1.webcache > 10.20.2.102.50317: Flags [S.], cksum 0x57e7 (correct), seq 446918562, ack 1229678911, win 29200, options [mss 1460,nop,nop,sackOK,nop,wscale 7], length 0
    11:30:06.179304 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 128, id 62079, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
        10.20.2.102.50314 > Server1.webcache: Flags [S], cksum 0x1bef (correct), seq 1931050208, win 64240, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 8,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0
    11:30:06.179394 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
        Server1.webcache > 10.20.2.102.50314: Flags [S.], cksum 0xdf0a (correct), seq 2621843822, ack 1931050209, win 29200, options [mss 1460,nop,nop,sackOK,nop,wscale 7], length 0
    11:30:06.181185 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 128, id 62080, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
        10.20.2.102.50315 > Server1.webcache: Flags [S], cksum 0x7b62 (correct), seq 1808868532, win 64240, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 8,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0
    11:30:06.181249 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
        Server1.webcache > 10.20.2.102.50315: Flags [S.], cksum 0x7832 (correct), seq 3006388430, ack 1808868533, win 29200, options [mss 1460,nop,nop,sackOK,nop,wscale 7], length 0
    11:30:06.431882 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 128, id 62081, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
        10.20.2.102.50317 > Server1.webcache: Flags [S], cksum 0x595c (correct), seq 1229678910, win 64240, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 8,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0
    11:30:06.431969 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
        Server1.webcache > 10.20.2.102.50317: Flags [S.], cksum 0x57e7 (correct), seq 446918562, ack 1229678911, win 29200, options [mss 1460,nop,nop,sackOK,nop,wscale 7], length 0
    11:30:08.402585 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
        Server1.webcache > 10.20.2.102.50315: Flags [S.], cksum 0x7832 (correct), seq 3006388430, ack 1808868533, win 29200, options [mss 1460,nop,nop,sackOK,nop,wscale 7], length 0
    11:30:08.602590 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
        Server1.webcache > 10.20.2.102.50314: Flags [S.], cksum 0xdf0a (correct), seq 2621843822, ack 1931050209, win 29200, options [mss 1460,nop,nop,sackOK,nop,wscale 7], length 0
    11:30:09.002511 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
        Server1.webcache > 10.20.2.102.50317: Flags [S.], cksum 0x57e7 (correct), seq 446918562, ack 1229678911, win 29200, options [mss 1460,nop,nop,sackOK,nop,wscale 7], length 0
    11:30:09.999574 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 128, id 46329, offset 0, flags [none], proto TCP (6), length 40)
        gateway.49152 > Server1.webcache: Flags [S], cksum 0x3912 (correct), seq 5001, win 0, length 0
    11:30:09.999693 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 44)
        Server1.webcache > gateway.49152: Flags [S.], cksum 0x7d44 (correct), seq 1791215404, ack 5002, win 29200, options [mss 1460], length 0
    11:30:09.999890 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 47531, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 75)
        gateway.49152 > Server1.webcache: Flags [R.], cksum 0x2bf6 (correct), seq 1:36, ack 1, win 65467, length 35 [RST+ (Ref.Id: ?suf6sk4amEkP4kj2W8w4]
    11:30:10.179919 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 128, id 62082, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
        10.20.2.102.50314 > Server1.webcache: Flags [S], cksum 0x1bef (correct), seq 1931050208, win 64240, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 8,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0
    11:30:10.180006 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
        Server1.webcache > 10.20.2.102.50314: Flags [S.], cksum 0xdf0a (correct), seq 2621843822, ack 1931050209, win 29200, options [mss 1460,nop,nop,sackOK,nop,wscale 7], length 0
    11:30:10.181844 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 128, id 62083, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
        10.20.2.102.50315 > Server1.webcache: Flags [S], cksum 0x7b62 (correct), seq 1808868532, win 64240, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 8,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0
    11:30:10.181909 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
        Server1.webcache > 10.20.2.102.50315: Flags [S.], cksum 0x7832 (correct), seq 3006388430, ack 1808868533, win 29200, options [mss 1460,nop,nop,sackOK,nop,wscale 7], length 0
    11:30:10.431653 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 128, id 62084, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
        10.20.2.102.50317 > Server1.webcache: Flags [S], cksum 0x595c (correct), seq 1229678910, win 64240, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 8,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0
    11:30:10.431736 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
        Server1.webcache > 10.20.2.102.50317: Flags [S.], cksum 0x57e7 (correct), seq 446918562, ack 1229678911, win 29200, options [mss 1460,nop,nop,sackOK,nop,wscale 7], length 0
    11:30:14.002588 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
        Server1.webcache > 10.20.2.102.50247: Flags [S.], cksum 0xacca (correct), seq 380393816, ack 3187915306, win 29200, options [mss 1460,nop,nop,sackOK,nop,wscale 7], length 0
    11:30:14.202518 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
        Server1.webcache > 10.20.2.102.50246: Flags [S.], cksum 0xcdaa (correct), seq 3215572129, ack 1497625028, win 29200, options [mss 1460,nop,nop,sackOK,nop,wscale 7], length 0
    11:30:14.202553 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
        Server1.webcache > 10.20.2.102.50314: Flags [S.], cksum 0xdf0a (correct), seq 2621843822, ack 1931050209, win 29200, options [mss 1460,nop,nop,sackOK,nop,wscale 7], length 0
    11:30:14.402583 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
        Server1.webcache > 10.20.2.102.50315: Flags [S.], cksum 0x7832 (correct), seq 3006388430, ack 1808868533, win 29200, options [mss 1460,nop,nop,sackOK,nop,wscale 7], length 0
    11:30:14.602590 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
        Server1.webcache > 10.20.2.102.50249: Flags [S.], cksum 0xca29 (correct), seq 3355912456, ack 2761569575, win 29200, options [mss 1460,nop,nop,sackOK,nop,wscale 7], length 0
    11:30:14.602644 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
        Server1.webcache > 10.20.2.102.50317: Flags [S.], cksum 0x57e7 (correct), seq 446918562, ack 1229678911, win 29200, options [mss 1460,nop,nop,sackOK,nop,wscale 7], length 0
    11:30:14.999526 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 128, id 32202, offset 0, flags [none], proto TCP (6), length 40)
        gateway.49152 > Server1.webcache: Flags [S], cksum 0x3912 (correct), seq 5001, win 0, length 0
    11:30:14.999650 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 44)

    ...More of the same, left out for brevity...
   ```

Comment: Some time ago there was a very similar question and I gave an answer with tipps to find http blocking component, see:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64388362/telnet-unable-to-connect-to-remote-host-connection-refused-when-trying-to-conn/64388980

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Unfortunately, the problem you addressed was somewhat  similar but definitely not the same. 1. As stated, my port 8080 is open. My firewall is not set to block it. 2. Port 8080 is published to the Internet via the URL that I described, and 3. The "client" I am using to access the service is Chrome which is able to access anything on the Internet *except* my service. These things were checked before I entered this question. Something else is wrong here...

Comment: Accessing your service with a private IP 10.X.Y.Z is a different routing, than accessing it from the Internet with public IP. Check the IP behind your DNS name and you will see a different number. So there are more components on the way from your Chrome to the server. I don't know, if your server is in a Cloud, than there might be an EIP configuration, which has to be checked. If it is in classic datacenter, there might be a hardware loadbalancer. These components typically block communication on port 8080 - they use 443 or 80.

Comment: That is true, but I have a hardware firewall that receives the HTTP request over the Internet and forwards it to the Server. I established that the request is being received from the Internet using tcpdump (that is why I mentioned it in my question).. I send a request over the Internet, it reaches the firewall and is being properly forwarded to the server machine. The server is siimply not responding properly to the request. This is not a question of the request being lost because of a difference in IP addresses. The firewall allows the request to get through to the server.

Comment: The firewall has Port 8080 open both for the Internet IP address and for the IP address of the server. The server has Port 8080 open as well. Again: something else is wrong on the server. There are no other components (load balancers, etc) that would block the port. In fact, the fact that I can see the packets reaching the server using tcpdump should prove that there is nothing blocking the request.

Comment: One more thing: apparently there is no longer any "refused" connections. What is happening now is that the response is timing out (ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT error). This is pretty consistent now. Nothing is blocking the request. The server for some reason is simply not responding to any request coming from the Internet. I will edit my question to reflect this.

Comment: Can you show your tcpdump command and output?
I would investigate with netstat about, which IP and port combination are used by your Application to listen.